# RecycleView Module in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

New member, first post. I will try to be specific and clear. The following piece of code is taken from kivy's webpage regarding the [RecycleView module](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) . I would like to use this piece of code, however, I would prefer not to use the KV lang and the Builder, but write the code in pure Python 3. My attempt to add the RecycleBoxLayout class as a widget was a complete failure as the result is simply a black window. Only the addition of the "viewclass" is working. Obviously, there is something I don't understand or missing here. I have also attached my attempt to rewrite the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, in advance.

**Original Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
    default_size: None, dp(56)
    default_size_hint: 1, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**My *failed* attempt:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
        self.viewclass = Label
        layout = RecycleBoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(layout)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Kivy but I would highly recommend you to use `kv lang` as much as possible. Its nothing more than a concise python and it will make your code much cleaner.

if you read the documentation for `RecycleBoxLayout` its highly experimental and you should make use of what works.

That being said, your code looks okay but with a couple of problems. 
 1) Replace 
`self.viewclass = Label` with `self.viewclass = 'Label'` and

2) You havent specified the `height`, `size` and `orientation` parameters for your `RecycleBoxLayout` in your python code.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestions but it didn't work. However, I imported the code, as is, and used it (sort of like using a module) and it worked as advertised. I am not happy but I will settle with it for the time being, since the RecycleView module is currently highly experimental and support is limited. So, thanks again. I am marking your comment as correct.

Comment: Yes, I was experimenting the code for RV one step at a time. While `self.viewclass = 'Label'` is right, things were getting a little weird with the `height` for the RecycleBoxLayout. I built an app which is on the Google store that requires a lot of use of `RecycleView` and I did the same thing, copying the example code and then carried on from there. I found the documentation for RV on the site a bit difficult to understand but the example code is quite easy to understand

Comment: Hi, again. Could you point me to your app in Google store? How did you manage to create an apk?

Comment: sure.Here it is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.junejadipanshu.tweetment&hl=en . You can take a look at the documentations here https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging.html on How to package for android. I'm using Windows, and the easiest way is to make the apk with Buildozer

Comment: Hi; I've been trying to initiate the app but it crashes on startup. My Android phone is quite old but it should be able to run the app. Did you have any complaints so far?

Comment: I haven't actually. I have an Android 5.0 and it works quite well on my phone, so I don't have much idea about older phones. But I can say that almost everyone who has installed the app is running 5.0 or newer version (I have that information as a developer) but thanks for that information although I don't think I can do much about that, it must be Kivy specific issue. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe that the problem has to do with the older version of my phone, unfortunately... Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, I don't like the kv lang, and have yet to be convinced it's better than doing everything in code.

the sample from https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView would be created as follows.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw, default_size=(0, 28), default_size_hint=(1, None), size_hint_y=None,
                         touch_multiselect=True, multiselect=True, orientation='vertical')

        self.bind(minimum_height=self._min)

    def _min(self, inst, val):
        self.height = val

class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            if self.selected:
                Color(.0, 0.9, .1, .3)
            else:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        self.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)

    def _update_rect(self, inst, value):
        self.rect.pos = inst.pos
        self.rect.size = inst.size

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super().refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            if self.selected:
                Color(.0, 0.9, .1, .3)
            else:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(SelectableRecycleBoxLayout())
        self.viewclass = 'SelectableLabel'
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The order in the KV class is important. Not sure what *needs* to be where, but self.data needs to be modified AFTER the widget is added.

Comment: It looks great!! I finally found my way of doing things with RV. Despite the fact that it is still unfinished it works well and it is better than using the ListAdapter module. Thanks, anyway!!